# PHP XSLTProcessor alternative to transform To XML

Tags: php, xslt

I have issues when using `XSLTProcessor`, and unfortunately installing or changing parameters to `php.ini` is not an option...

I know that this class consists on:

```
 XSLTProcessor {
/* Methods */
function getParameter ( string $namespaceURI , string $localName ): string
public function getSecurityPrefs ( void ): int
function hasExsltSupport ( void ): bool
function importStylesheet ( object $stylesheet ): void
function registerPHPFunctions ([ mixed $restrict ] ): void
function removeParameter ( string $namespaceURI , string $localName ): bool
function setParameter ( string $namespace , string $name , string $value ): bool
function setProfiling ( string $filename ): bool
public function setSecurityPrefs ( int $securityPrefs ): int
function transformToDoc ( DOMNode $doc ): DOMDocument
function transformToURI ( DOMDocument $doc , string $uri ): int
function transformToXML ( DOMDocument $doc ): string
}
```

So I would like to sustitute following lines of code without installing it on server (**Thank you so much Goddady!**) `importStyleSheet` AND `transformToXML`

```
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($XSL);
$RESULT = $proc->transformToXML($xdoc);
```

Which PHP class or library could do the same job? 
Do you have an example?

Comment: I think, "Xalan" is the buzz word, you should search for, since this is in an Apache environment the standard XSLT processor which PHP uses normally. However, it is NOT written in PHP, so I highly doubt that you get it to run without any installtion etc.

Comment: PHP 5 uses libxml and libxslt from http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/ and not Xalan as far as I am aware. I don't think there is a pure PHP implementation of an XSLT processor.